# gdb error without -pg

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I want to debug the following program with gdb:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double take_log(double a)
{
    return log(a);
}

int main()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    printf("%lf\n", take_log(32));
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with -g and run without an issue:

```
$ cc test.c -g -o lm -lm
$ lm
hello world
3.465736
```

But when I start gdb to debug, I get a segmentation fault:

```
$ gdb lm
[gdb startup message here]
(gdb) start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40065b: file test.c, line 11.
Starting program: [path to program]/lm 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7de711b in check_match.12080 () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Oddly enough, if I add the profiler option -pg to the compiler, then gdb runs without issues:

```
$ cc test.c -g -pg -o lm -lm
$ gdb lm
[gdb startup message]
(gdb) start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4007f5: file test.c, line 11.
Starting program: [path to program]/lm 
Executing new program: [path to program]/lm
main () at test.c:11
11      printf("hello world\n");
(gdb) next
hello world
12      printf("%lf\n", take_log(32));
(gdb) next
3.465736
13      return 0;
(gdb) next
14  }
(gdb)
```

Even more oddly (or perhaps due to the same reason), if I omit the -pg option during compilation, but also comment out the line

```
// printf("hello world\n");
```

then gdb runs without issues again.

What is happening here?

Here's some more details that may help:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

$ echo $LIBRARY_PATH

$ ldd lm
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff7ffe000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffff7d64000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffff79eb000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000555555554000)

$ cc -v
[...] gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux)
```

Comment: I just checked all your steps and on my Ubuntu (64BIT) machine doesn't happens that. [See here](http://pastebin.com/raw/US0KWhRJ)

Comment: Can you add these to your question? cc version, OS distribution, contents of `~/.gdbinit` if any, contents of `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `$LIBRARY_PATH`,  and the output of `ldd buggy-version-of-lm` ?

Comment: @Michi Thanks for checking.  I assumed what I'm seeing isn't what you'd expect.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick  Thanks for the suggestion, please see the added details.  There's no .gdbinit file.

Comment: I compiled with: `gcc -ggdb -c untitled.c -o untitled.o -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pendatic -std-gnu99 -I.`    I compiled with: `gcc  -ggdb untitled.o -o untitled`  Then I ran it from a command line: the output was correct. (cont)

Comment: (cont) then I ran it with `gdb untitled` and entered the following into gdb: `(gdb) br main`  `(gdb) r`  `(gdb) c`
then gdb output the following:
`Continuing.
hello world
3.465736
[Inferior 1 (process 14483) exited normally]
(gdb) `   which indicates it ran correctly with no seg fault